# How to increment a html class name in a Jquery for each loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

I am pulling a set of data from a JSON file, which returns around 12 results (so far). Issue is, I need to display an image within the results, which is not being grabbed from the JSON, so will be added in from the 'IMG' directory.

One way I want to do this is to add the image to a class name in the return below, but not sure how i can increment the class name up by 1 for each new JSON return.

Below is how I am getting the data and appending this to the html:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/js/vehicles.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data.cars).each(function (index, value) {
            console.log(value.name);
            $('#car_range').append($('\
                <div class="card_3 card">\
                    <div class="card_img_main">\
                        <p>' + value.advert_classification + '</p>\
                        <div class="car_filters">\
                            <span>' + value.odometer_value + value.odometer_units + '</span>\
                            <span>EV</span>\
                            <span>' + value.body_type + '</span>\
                            <span>' + value.body_type + '</span>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="card_stats">\
                        <div class="car_details">\
                            <p class="car_make">' + value.make + '<span><i class="far fa-star"></i></span></p>\
                            <p class="car_model">' + value.model + '</p>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="car_price">\
                            <p class="car_monthly_price">£' + value.price + ' <span>/mo (PCP)</span></p>\
                            <p class="car_total_price discount">£' + value.price + ' <span class="old_price">£' + value.price_when_new + '</span> <span><a href="">Calculate finance</a></span></p>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            '));
        })
    }
})
```

The class 'card_image_main' is what I want to increment, so each new data set returns like:

- card_image_main_1
- card_image_main_2
- card_image_main_3 etc....

Can someone help?

Comment: Well you need a counter variable then. Since you are using `.each(function (index, value)`, you don't need to create and increment one yourself here, you already have one - `index`. (That is zero-based, so increase the value you append to your classname by 1, if you need them starting at 1 and not 0.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable in the loop that increments as the loop goes on. such as n++, and to change the class name, simple insert code such as this inside the for loop. This code adds the next class, and removes the previous class:

```
var class = 'card_image_main' + String(n);
var previousClass = 'card_image_main' + String(n - 1);
element.classList.remove(previousClass);
element.classList.add(class);
```